# Animate on delay jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I have made a simple jquery animation and can't see why its not working...

I know I am missing something really simple.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aBWh6/9/

and the code

```
$(function(){
   $('.button2').animate({
       opacity: 0.4,
       marginLeft: "10px"
   }, 5000 );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to include jQuery. On the left side panel of jsfiddle you should expand *No-Library (Pure JS)* select and choose jQuery (the lates would be the best). Then reload your fiddle (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd>) and everything works fine!

Also, if you really want it to move *on delay*, you will need to use this:

```
$(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $('.button2').animate({
         opacity: 0.4,
         marginLeft: "10px"
      }, 500 );
   }, 5000);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aBWh6/13/

The number value behind animate equals the duration of the animation, not delay.

Comment: Thanks very much, I knew it would be something obvious :-)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

you forgot to add jQuery library

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aBWh6/10/)

```
$(function(){
   $('.button2').animate({
       opacity: 0.4,
       marginLeft: "10px"
   }, 5000 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/aBWh6/12/ . Include the jquery library files in the jsfiddle to make you code working

```
 $( ".button2" ).animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, 5000 );
```